# What would be the best way to implement arguments into input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, arguments

How exactly would I implement args into a users input. For example, the program asks for input and then say a command could be help. From here it would print a help menu, however if I supplied extra arguments in the input such as `-extra` it would print more help info.
Would using `if` statements be the best way?
However, I'm not too sure how I could get the arguments from specific options eg if the user entered `help --command exit` how would I detect that they had entered some additional args and execute the right code to do so.
Currently, my main idea is just to use if statements sort of like what follows:

```py
cmd == input("enter a cmd: ")
if cmd == "help":
   print("help menu here")
elif cmd == "help -extra":
    print("extra help info")
elif # function to parse additional non required arguments
```

So far all I've tried is the if statement but I'm not sure what else I could do, because if i were to have a lot of commands I would definitely has way too many if statements.

Comment: Why don't you use the `argparse` module?

Comment: ...or [click](https://pypi.org/project/click/)